# Annotation map pin title showing wrongly

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, mkmapview, mkannotationview

Annotation pin title shows same title for all pins.  I have set label to show the title of each pin  but I am getting same title for all labels.  I did NSLog
of lbl.text and in NSLog it shows different title.

Why am I getting same title for all map pins.

```
    -(void)maprequests
    {

    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    // getting an NSString
    NSString *emailid = [prefs stringForKey:@"email"];
    NSString *deviceid = [Request UDID];
    //NSString * walkGUID=[prefs stringForKey:@"walkguid"];
    //NSLog(@"walkGUID:%@",walkGUID);
    NSString * walkguid=[prefs stringForKey:@"walkguid"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://10.0.0.28/web/ws/get_poilist_walks.php?strEmailID=%@&strDeviceID=%@&strWalkGuid=%@",emailid,deviceid,walkguid]];

    NSLog(@"%@",url);

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    //AFNetworking asynchronous url request
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    operation.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        self.pointofintrests = [responseObject objectForKey:@"PointOfIntrests"];
                NSIndexPath *indexpath;

        NSDictionary *tempDictionary= [self.pointofintrests objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];

        for (NSDictionary *dictionary in _pointofintrests)
        {
            MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } };
            NSString * latitude= [dictionary objectForKey:@"Latitude"];
            NSString * longitude =[dictionary objectForKey:@"Longitude"];
            double strlatitude = [latitude doubleValue];
            double strlongitude = [longitude doubleValue];
            region.center.latitude =strlatitude;
            region.center.longitude =  strlongitude;
            region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
            region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;
            [_mapview setRegion:region animated:YES];
            [_mapview setDelegate:self];

            DisplayMap *ann = [[DisplayMap alloc] init];
            ann.coordinate = region.center;

            [_mapview addAnnotation:ann];

        }

    }
     failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
     {
        NSLog(@"Request Failed: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);

    }];

    [operation start];



}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation{

    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = nil;
    UILabel *label;
    if(annotation != mapView.userLocation)
    {

        static NSString *defaultPinID = @"com.invasivecode.pin";
        pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];
        if ( pinView == nil ) pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                                         initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID];

        if(![annotation isKindOfClass:[DisplayMap class]])
            return nil;

        DisplayMap *a = (DisplayMap *)annotation;
        pinView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"push_pin@2x"];


        UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 30, 250, 30)];
        lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        lbl.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        lbl.alpha = 0.5;
        lbl.tag = 42;
        for (int i=0; i<_pointofintrests.count; i++)
        {
        lbl.text = [[_pointofintrests valueForKey:@"title"] objectAtIndex:i];
        }
        [pinView addSubview:lbl];

        [_mapview selectAnnotation:pinView animated:YES];

        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
        pinView.animatesDrop = NO;

    }
    else
    {


    }


     return pinView;

   }
```

Comment: Set the annotation's title property to the title _when you add the annotation_ and then you can just set lbl.text to annotation.title (no need to look up anything because the data will be _with_ the annotation object itself).

Comment: You also have a _lot_ of other issues with this code (handling annotation view re-use, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are looping over `_pointofinterests`

```
for (int i=0; i<_pointofintrests.count; i++)
{
    lbl.text = [[_pointofintrests valueForKey:@"title"] objectAtIndex:i];
}
```

This isn't doing what you think. Its assigning the last title in the array to every pin.

Because the `viewForAnnotation` delegate method gives you the annotation that will display, I tend to keep an array of annotations to save the index, and therefore you can access your data correctly.

When you call `[_mapview addAnnotation:ann];` also save `ann` into an array.

You should then be able todo something like:

```
[[_pointofintrests valueForKey:@"title"] objectAtIndex:[annArray indexOfObject:annotation]]
```

As a side note, if `_pointofinterests` is an `NSDictionary` I would use `objectForKey` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason you are getting the same label text on all pins is, as already pointed out in another answer, that for every pin, `lbl.text` is always set to the title of the last object in `_pointofintrests`.

The solution I would prefer however is to set the annotation's `title` and use that to set the label's text.

1. When creating the annotation and before calling `addAnnotation`, set its `title` property:

   ```
   DisplayMap *ann = [[DisplayMap alloc] init];
   ann.coordinate = region.center;
   ann.title = [dictionary objectForKey:@"title"];  //<-- add this line
   [_mapview addAnnotation:ann];
   ```
2. In `viewForAnnotation`, instead of the `for` loop, you can simply set the label's text to the annotation's title (no searching of arrays or looping):

   ```
   //for (int i=0; i<_pointofintrests.count; i++)
   //{
   //    lbl.text = [[_pointofintrests valueForKey:@"title"] objectAtIndex:i];
   //}

   lbl.text = annotation.title;
   ```

That technically fixes the problem of the same text appearing on all pins.

However, there are some other issues with the code in `viewForAnnotation` which will become apparent after the above fix:

- The `UILabel` is being added to the annotation view even if the annotation view was dequeued (meaning a previously created view is being re-used).  That dequeued view will *already* have a `UILabel` in it and the existing code will add another one on top.  After panning and zooming the map for a while, you will notice overlapping labels for each pin.

  **The `UILabel` should only be added when a new view is created (when the dequeue returns `nil` and you `alloc`+`init` a new one).**
- Another problem is that since you are using a custom image for your annotations, you should create a plain `MKAnnotationView` instead of an `MKPinAnnotationView`.  The `MKPinAnnotationView` class is designed for showing the standard, built-in pin image and although it still has an `image` property, it tends to sometimes ignore that and revert to showing its standard pin image.
- Another problem is this line:

  ```
  [_mapview selectAnnotation:pinView animated:YES];
  ```

  - The map view can only have one annotation "selected" at a time so if you were thinking that calling this in `viewForAnnotation` would show the callout for all the annotations at once, then that is mistaken.
  - The `selectAnnotation` method requires the *annotation* as the first parameter.  The `pinView` is not the annotation -- it is the annotation's *view* (they are not the same thing).  The compiler must be complaining about this line and at run-time, the system is probably showing an error in the console saying something like "Trying to select an annotation which has not been added".  So technically, the line should be `[_mapview selectAnnotation:annotation animated:YES];`
  - **Regardless, do not call `selectAnnotation` in the `viewForAnnotation` delegate method.**  Doing so may lead to recursion and a stack overflow (and an EXC_BAD_ACCESS) because the select causes the annotation's view to be updated which causes viewForAnnotation to be called, etc.  Instead, call it in the `didAddAnnotationViews` delegate method for the *one* annotation you want to show the callout for.

Your revised `viewForAnnotation` delegate method might look like this:

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if(! [annotation isKindOfClass:[DisplayMap class]])
    {
        return nil;
    }

    static NSString *defaultPinID = @"MyPin";

    int lblTag = 42;

    MKAnnotationView *pinView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];
    if (pinView == nil)
    {
        pinView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID];
        pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"push_pin@2x"];
        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;

        //Create and add the label to the view ONCE when creating the view... 
        UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 30, 250, 30)];
        lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        lbl.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        lbl.alpha = 0.5;
        lbl.tag = lblTag;
        [pinView addSubview:lbl];
    }
    else
    {
        //If we are re-using a dequeued view
        //update its annotation reference...
        //(otherwise view will still be pointing to its previous annotation)
        pinView.annotation = annotation;
    }

    //At this point, we have a new or dequeued view 
    //pointing to the current annotation.
    //Now update the label that will already be there
    //with the current annotation's title...
    UILabel *lbl = (UILabel *)[pinView viewWithTag:lblTag];
    lbl.text = annotation.title;

    return pinView;
}
```

Remember you'll need to set the annotation's `title` as shown at the top of the answer as well.

There are also some things in the `for` loop in the `maprequests` method that I want to point out:

- It's not necessary to create and set a region just to set the annotation's coordinate.  Calling `setRegion` in the loop is pointless and inefficient since the user will only end up seeing the map positioned at the last annotation anyway.  To set an annotation coordinate, just do:

  ```
  ann.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(strlatitude, strlongitude);
  ```
- You can call `setRegion` (once) *after* the `for` loop (or just call `[_mapview showAnnotations:_mapview.annotations animated:YES];` so you don't have to yourself calculate the region that shows all the annotations).
- You don't need to set the map view's `delegate` inside the `for` loop repeatedly.  Set the `delegate` (once) *before* the `for` loop (though it should already have been set long before this method is called).